# fetching images in a list

Tags: list, sharepoint-server

I am not expecting ready made solution here so please don't down vote me.

I want to load #tag images from Instagram in a list. Are there any examples I can refer?

I tried to Google but not able to find much help.

Comment: How are you planning to execute this.. button click or daily job etc?

Comment: @AmalHashim   Daily job. I mean timer job which runs say every 10 min

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is kind of off-topic.

To implement this you need to use API's provided by [Instagram](https://instagram.com/developer/)
Then using C# connect to there service end points and read the images etc.

Now comes the on-topic part - You need to load this into SharePoint. For that you can refer following links

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468469/how-do-you-upload-a-file-to-a-document-library-in-sharepoint

Comment: do you have example on how to call instagram API from sharepoint? I really dont know anything of this.  So basically i call API and get images and then upload to sharepoint folder? Is there any code to upload image in list?

Comment: It doesn't matter from SharePoint etc.. Using C# you can do this refer link https://gist.github.com/fraga/4108898 Now **to LIST you can't upload files**.. for that you need to use library..for upload to library refer the link in my answer.

Comment: What kind of library i need to use to upload to list. could be nice to have that example as well

Comment: Since you are using daily job, you should use SharePoint server Side API... You can create a project in visual studio and follow the link in my answer.

Comment: But what about examples of loading images in list?

Comment: Once you have images loaded into the library you can just drop a list view webpart and that will display the images